# WiFi: Connect to a network with hidden SSID in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I have Windows 7 with the following station:
`D-Link DWA-160 Xtreme N Dual Band USB Adapter(rev.A2)` (driver version 3.5.0.21).

I'm trying to connect to a wireless network that has an hidden SSID with the command:

```
Netsh wlan connect name="myNetworkProfile"
```

The profile is configured to connect even if the network is not broadcasting its name (SSID).
Despite that, the command fails *promptly* every time with the message:

> The network specified by profile "myNetworkProfile" is not available
> to connect.

Nonetheless, when trying to connect manually using the dialog box (see image below), it successfully connects to the network after about 10 or 15 seconds.
[image]

Also, Please - no need to elaborate about how useless the hidden SSID feature is.

Answer (score -1):

original answer: netsh wlan connect ssid=YOURSSID name=PROFILENAME

updated answer: netsh wlan connect ssid=YOURSSID name=PROFILENAME nonBroadcast=yes

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work...

Comment: what about this: netsh wlan connect ssid=YOURSSID name=PROFILENAME nonBroadcast=yes

Comment: Isn't it identical as the previous one?

Comment: the previous one did not have "nonBroadcast=yes" I updated the answer

Comment: Sorry but still doesn't work